# How to use Zend_File_Transfer?

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, zend-file

I have been using normal file upload element to upload files and validate them. But recently, I found out that implementing a Zend_file_tranfer gives much control over the file.

I am searched Everywhere in the internet searching for a simple example to get started with it, but none of them show how they are linked to the element. I dont know where to create the object of Zend_File_Transfer, and how to add it to the element? I basically dont know, how to use it.

Can anyone give me a beginners example of using zend_File_tranfers, in both zend_form and Zend_Controller_Action

Comment: I am hoping I asked a understandable question. Basically I want simple guide from a beginner point of view for using Zend_File_Transfer, to control file uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your form do something like this in your form:

```
$image = $this->getElement('image');
//$image = new Zend_Form_Element_File();
$image->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH. "/../data/images"); //!!!!
$extension = $image->getFileName();
if (!empty($extension))
    {
        $extension = @explode(".", $extension);
        $extension = $extension[count($extension)-1];
        $image->addFilter('Rename', sprintf('logo-%s.'.$extension, uniqid(md5(time()), true)));
    }

$image
    ->addValidator('IsImage', false, $estensioni)//doesn't work on WAMPP/XAMPP/LAMPP
    ->addValidator('Size',array('min' => '10kB', 'max' => '1MB', 'bytestring' => true))//limit to 200k
    ->addValidator('Extension', false, $estensioni)// only allow images to be uploaded
    ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
            'minwidth' => $img_width_min,
            'minheight' => $img_height_min,
            'maxwidth' => $img_width_max,
            'maxheight' => $img_height_max
            )
        )
    ->addValidator('Count', false, 1);// ensure that only 1 file is uploaded
// set the enctype attribute for the form so it can upload files
$this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
```

Then when you submit your form in your controller:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $data = $form->getValues();//also transfers the file
....
```

Answer (score 2):

In form:

```
class Application_Form_YourFormName extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setAction('/index/upload')->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $upload_file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('new_file');
        $new_file->setLabel('File to Upload')->setDestination('./tmp');
        $new_file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
        $new_file->addValidator('Size', false, 67108864);
        $new_file->addValidator('Extension', false, Array('png', 'jpg'));

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Upload');

        $this->addElements(array($upload_file, $submit));
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
class Application_Controller_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function uploadAction()
    {
        $this->uform = new Application_Form_YourFormName();
        $this->uform->new_file->receive();
        $file_location = $this->uform->new_file->getFileName();

        // .. do the rest...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that can help you.

[Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html)

[Same Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380921/zend-zend-file-transfer-adapter-http-renaming-question)

[Step By Step Toturial](http://ahsangill.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/zend-framework-file-upload-using-zend_form_element_file/)

[Another Useful Link](http://www.developer.com/lang/php/article.php/3844031/Managing-File-Uploads-with-the-Zend-Framework.htm)